# What does "Remove this app" in the Firebase console really do? ...beyond stopping the collection of analytics data

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Have an old iOS & Android app that uses Firebase to authenticate & Firestore as a back end.

I just want to shut it down. i.e. stop authentication & Firestore access.
I know that's not polite but the app is causing real problems for other apps in the project.

Thought [Google support: Delete Firebase App](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7047853) sounded promising but reading the documentation it seems like this doesn't do much more than stop the collection of analytic data - which doesn't sound like app removal at all.

Was hoping for something more dramatic but am reticent to try as removal is a one-way street.
I removed the app's OAuth clients in the Google APIs console credentials page but that didn’t have any effect on signing up, signing in ...which also seems weird.

So, would appreciate if anybody could shed more light on what removing an iOS & Android app from a Firebase project really does?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the App from your Firebase project removes the credentials available to apps that may wish to log in and use your project's services, being Firestore, Realtime DB, Cloud Functions, FCM, etc . This does not disable or remove the functionality within your app client which would throw errors when the app credentials are invalid.

Comment: I see! Deleting removes credentials needed by external apps to access the project's services - but doesn't stop stuff from working. That makes sense. I'd upvote but need some reputation first. Thanks!